# "Bindable" capability does not work in all situations

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, bindable

When I try to set the width of a BorderContainer to a bindable variable in Flex tags declaration it works well. Code looks something like this:

```
<s:BorderContainer id="mainContent" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" backgroundAlpha="1" backgroundColor="0xfee6ca" 
                               borderVisible="false">
                <s:layout>
                    <s:VerticalLayout/>
                </s:layout>
      <s:BorderContainer id="containedBc" width={mainContent.width} />
    </s:BorderContainer>
```

When I try to change the width of "mainContent", the width of "containedBc" is updated also.

But when I try to add the "containedBc" BorderContainer from an actionScript class, the width of "containdBc" does not vary when I try to change mainContent's width. Can you explain me why this? And how to resolve it?

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question.  Tip: You should put your answer into an actual "Answer" below so others can find it easier and they can also upvote it.

Comment: Resolved at your thought:) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When need to use bindable capability from actionscript3, you can use BindingUtils.bindProperty(...) function. Hope to help you:)